# Can't edit a title for the html page

Tags: railstutorial.org

I've tried this with multiple apps, but in each case, adding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Custom Title </title>
    </head>
</html>
```

does not change the title as displayed in the web browser. Changing anything else in the file 'app/views/index.html.erb' works fine, however. It seems to be only in the title. I'm using Ruby v2.2.1 and Rails v4.2.1.

Comment: Adding to where? What does the *resulting* HTML look like? Is it [valid](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) ?

Comment: Adding to 'app/views/index.html.erb' or any other page in the views folder. I tried adding it anywhere in the page. The resulting page title in the web browser is the name of the app itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a new Rails application, you need to change the HTML in `layouts/application.html.erb` if you want to change something in `head`.

`app/views/index.html.erb` does not represent the entire content of the page in your browser but only the view, in Rails it is mixed with some layouts depending of your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The page title is probably being supplied by your layout.  Look in views/layouts and see if there is a file called application.html.erb that provides a title (and doctype).  If you don't have a layout, you probably should.

You can verify this by looking at the source for the page once it loads.  See if there are two  sections.